# Setting Cache-Control and Expires headers for the end client only

Tags: cache, cache-control, expires

I am trying to add explicit caching to 301 redirects. However, I am worried that a permanent redirect for one user might not be permanent for another user. So I'd like to use `Cache-Control: no-cache` so that upstream servers like my ISP don't cache that request (I believe that's how this works).

This leaves the Expires header which I've set to one month in the future. But the combination of Cache-Control no-cache and Expires headers makes me think I'm doing it wrong. I'd like for an individual user to have a cached request, but avoid ISP/upstream caching. How should I set up my caching headers on redirects?

Answer (score 1):

Ah! I want `Cache-Control: private`. See the tutorial here: http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/#EXPIRES